# Cannot Access Wordpress Theme Option nor Website Now

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having some problems with my theme-options.php & now I'm unable to edit any of appearance options nor the website opens.

My Wordpress Site: 
http://www.dryerventcleaninghouston.com/

This is where the error occurs:

```
<div class="postbox">
  <h3><?php _e("Homepage Featured Left", 'studiopress'); ?></h3>
    <div class="inside">
      <p><?php _e("Select which category you want displayed:", 'studiopress'); ?><br />
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories(array('selected' => get_theme_mod('featured_top_left'), 'name' => $settings.'[featured_top_left]', 'orderby' => 'Name' , 'hierarchical' => 1, 'hide_empty' => '0' )); ?></p>

      <p><?php _e("Number of posts to show:", 'studiopress'); ?><br />
      <input type="text" name="<?php echo $settings; ?>[featured_top_left_num]" value="<?php echo get_theme_mod('featured_top_left_num'); ?>" size="5" /></p>

      <p><?php _e("Thumbnail dimensions (Width x Height)", 'studiopress'); ?><br />
      <input type="text" name="<?php echo $settings; ?>[featured_top_left_thumb_width]" value="<?php echo get_theme_mod('featured_top_left_thumb_width'); ?>" size="3" /> x <input type="text" name="<?php echo $settings; ?>[featured_top_left_thumb_height]" value="<?php echo get_theme_mod('featured_top_left_thumb_height'); ?>" size="3" /></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The name variable in the dropdown categories array...$settings.'[

The name index in the array your passing to wp_dropdown_categories.. depending on what is in your settings variable needs to look like this

'name' => $settings['featured_top_left'],

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little, as I'm a bit new to this. Should I add '[ Also advise on how to edit this as I cannot access editor now.

Comment: You would have to get the file via ftp at this point...i would never recommend doing work on theme/plugin files through the wordpress admin unless you know exactly what your doing...it always helps to have a backup downloaded locally..

Comment: Yeah, I should have done that. Now I have to fix the error & replace the file using ftp. Can anybody please fix the above error.